# What counts as an armored target?

Tags: tribes-ascend

Many weapon upgrades you can unlock provide a damage bonus vs. armored targets. Simply put, what are armored targets? Do players in heavy armor count?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, players never count as heavy armor.

What counts as heavy armor are:

- Vehicles
- Base Turrets / Scanners / Generator
- Deployable player packs, such as the Engineer Turret
- The armor supply drop that you can call from the sky with 2000 credits

Comment: Are you sure Generator does counts as "armored"? It's a different category from other base-assets, code-wise, and can be damaged by bullet weapons.

Comment: I don't believe Generators or deployable assets count as armored. A loading tip suggested that only things that are exclusively damaged by explosives, and shrikes, count as armored. This means Shrikes, Tanks, Base Turrets and Sensors.